# Connecting to a headless Server for gaming?

Tags: server, minecraft, headless

So I'm kind of in deep already with this but basically, I put together a computer its got everything in it EXCEPT a GPU. My thought process here was to connect to it from my main computer and use it as like a dedicated server mostly for Minecraft, I got everything running (I think, the lights are on and nothings exploded) but I'm a little stumped as to the connecting part. Should it already have a OS on it? if so how do I put one on? I'm still a little new to computers so this might be more than I can chew but help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it needs an Operating System.

The Minecraft Server is an application that runs on top of that OS.

Minecraft Server (Java) runs very well on Ubuntu Server. I have one running right now.

There are many tutorials on your favorite Search Engine for each step:

- Installing Ubuntu Server onto your hardware.
- Using SSH so you don't need to leave a keyboard/monitor attached to the server
- Downloading and installing Minecraft Server (Java).
- Using the `screen` or `tmux` applications to keep the Minecraft Server application running when you are not logged in.
- Using systemd .service files to automate starting and stopping the server at startup and shutdown.
- Basic networking so players can connect to your shiny new server.